# Can I use WebHttpBinding and NetNamedPipeBinding at the same time?

Tags: .net, wcf

For a REST based service, running with `WebHttpBinding`, can I add the capability for inter-service communication on the same machine with `NetNamedPipeBinding`, so that it is faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, you want to add multiple of endpoints with different Bindings.

for example:

```
<service name = "MyService">
<endpoint
address = "http://localhost:8000/MyService"
binding = "wsHttpBinding"
contract = "IMyContract"
/>
<endpoint
address = "net.tcp://localhost:8001/MyService"
binding = "netTcpBinding"
contract = "IMyContract"
/>
<endpoint
address = "net.tcp://localhost:8002/MyService"
binding = "netTcpBinding"
contract = "IMyOtherContract"
/>
</service>
```